# .hash give EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKBOINT

Tags: ios, swift, reflection, hash

I'm trying to implement the Hashable protocol on my object using [EVCloudKitDao](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao) where all properties will be used for the hash by using reflection. For some of the properties I'm getting the error:

> EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKBOINT

When I filter out the key's that has this problem, then sometimes key that went ok before will suddenly get this error.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

The entire code that has this problem can be found at: [EVReflection.swift](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/master/AppMessage/AppMessage/CloudKit/EVReflection.swift)

I get the error the moment i request a .hash on an object that has the EVCloudKitDataObject as it's base object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was cause because of an Int overflow. After changing the code what you see below the error was gone:

```
    public class func hashValue(theObject: NSObject) -> Int {
    var hash : Int = 0
    var counter : Int = 0
    for (key, value) in toDictionary(theObject) {
        hash = hash &+ (value.hash << counter)
        counter = counter + 1
    }
    return Int(hash)
}
```

For more information see the 'Overflow operators' section in the apple documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

Now even simplified and using the 31 * old hash + newhash :

```
public class func hashValue(theObject: NSObject) -> Int {
    return Int(map(toDictionary(theObject)) {$1}.reduce(0) {(31 &* $0) &+ $1.hash})
}
```